# How do I replace <code> HTML tags with backticks in Atom?

Tags: html, regex, markdown, atom-editor

I have been trying to switch between a WordPress blog and a Jekyll blog. As part of this I would like to convert `<code>` tags (and its closing tag `</code>`) with backticks (`). My text editor is [Atom](https://atom.io) and I would like to be able to automate this action using Atom's RegEx search function.

Comment: Search: `"</?code>"` ... Replace with: ``"`"`` (without the quotes)  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search:

```
</?code>
```

Replace with:

```
`
```

---

The regex `</?code>` matches either `<code>` or `</code>`, because the [`?` quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) makes the preceding token optional (the `/`).